# Can't generate GtkBuilder.xml in glade

Tags: python, gtk, glade, gtkbuilder

I'm trying to design some window in glade, and I want it to use in my python code using GtkBuilder

I just somehow can't generate GtkBuilder xml

When I save something in Glade I get .glade file

Can you please help me how can I generate GtkBuilder xml?

```
$ rpm -q glade3
glade3-3.10.0-2.fc15.x86_64
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the following on Ubuntu 10.04 but I guess it should work on your system as well. If you are using `glade-3` when you are saving the file, select *Save As...* option instead of *Save*, you will prompted to enter the file name with file browser displayed. Here in the bottom left corner you can see selection options for file format like:
**File Formats**
() GtkBuilder
() Libglade

(sorry cant upload image ): )

Select **GtkBuilder** option and save as the filename.xml of your choice. That should do it!
To cross check if the generated file is .glade file or GtkBuilder compatible XML file (as both are in XML format) root node in .glade file will be `glade-interface` whereas in GtkBuilder compatible XML file it will be `interface`

If you have an existing .glade file you can look into [gtk-builder-convert](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-builder-convert.html) script to convert to GtkBuilder compatible XML file.
Hope this helps!

Comment: this is how I did it, but when I run the xml I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 49, in <module>
    w = Window()
  File "./main.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.builder.add_from_file('main.xml')
glib.GError: Invalid object type `GtkGrid'

Comment: @javo: What is the version of Gtk+ you are using? Looks like GtkGrid is part of Gtk+3. In main.xml what does the line `<requires lib="gtk+" version="XXX"/>` say the version required is? Do you get any option to select the version of Gtk+ when you launch glade?

Comment: As another.anon.coward says, GtkGrid is part of GTK 3. So depending of the version of the GTK Library (which according to your Ubuntu version and [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu) is GTK 2.20), you need to set in your glade project properties that version, so that it knows which widgets are available. See the [project properties dialog](http://tadeboro.github.com/Glade3/figures/preferences-dialog.png).

Comment: Ooops, another.anon.coward uses Ubuntu 10.04, but you, javo, use Fedora 15, so your GTK version is 3.0. If you have an error it means you're probably not using the right bindings. pygtk is no more used, it's gobject-instrospection that is used with GTK 3. So don't use in your python code the `import pygtk` but instead: `from gi.repository import Gtk`. Read these links: https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject and http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @liberforce: distro should not really matter I think,  what matters is the version of GTK that is being "used" (there can be multiple installation ... I know that you know!!) You can always install latest version from source :), anyway as you have pointed out, I could not find any python bindings for GTK+ 3

Comment: It's just that for GTK 3, the old pyGTK bindings have been replaced by new bindings that use pyGObject. The introspection features of GObject help in the bindings maintenance, which was more difficult in pyGTK.

Comment: @liberforce: Thanks for the piece of info! The thing is I have not used pyGtk as such, only Gtk+ 2.x &  glade -_-;

Answer (score 0):

May this tutor be of some help ?

http://www.learningpython.com/2006/05/07/creating-a-gui-using-pygtk-and-glade/

Comment: that tutorial is using glade instead of GtkBuilder, I was told that GtkBuilder is some kind of replacement and I should use it instead of Glade, now I have .glade file and I want .xml file

Comment: Why do you want GTKbuilder ? Just use the glade file, as shown, it works great !

Comment: @Louis: GtkBuilder or LibGlade *is* the format the XML used in the glade file. What he wants is a glade file with GtkBuilder XML in it.